# DoCmd.Close acForm, "Name", acSavePrompt not working

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have some VBA code, like this:

```
Private Sub Command150_Click()

DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_requirements_reference", , , , acFormAdd
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
Forms!frm_requirements_reference!fk_requirement.Value = Me!txt_form_requirement_id.Value
Forms!frm_requirements_reference!Requirement_Name.Value = Me!Requirement_Name.Value
Forms!frm_requirements_reference!Combo7.SetFocus

DoCmd.Close acForm, "Formular_Requirements", acSavePrompt

End Sub
```

In general, I am the most interested about that last line of code. It just closes the form "Formular_Requirements", however no prompt on save YES / NO comes. Don't you know, where that problem could be?

Thank you for help,

Vaclav

Comment: It's been a while since I've done any Access development, but if I recall correctly it only prompts if the form is dirty -- that is, if there are changes to be saved.  And it's about the changes to the form's *design,* not its data, so there probably are no changes to be saved.

Comment: Hi Phoog, 
yes, you are right. I also found solution, how to do that. I had to add: 
`DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord`
this works

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using MS Access.

If I understand your problem well, saving data is automatically handled by the currency manager.

For example, if you edit a row, and

- Click "Next Record"

or

- The corresponding table fields lose focus

The record edited is automatically saved.

Comment: "I guess you are using MS Access": this is explicit in the question's tags.